# Sublime Text 2 OS X Command Line

Tags: macos, command-line, sublimetext2

I just reinstalled Sublime Text 3 build 3047 and upon doing so, I lost the ability to type subl . in the command line and go straight to the Sublime Text editor.  This is the message that I get when I type subl . in the command line.

```
    bash: subl: command not found
```

When I run the command below from the instructions on Sublime's website,

```
    ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

I get the following message

```
    ln: /Users/david/bin/subl: No such file or directory
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you have an existing `~/bin` directory?

Comment: yes, i believe i do.  I am a newbie, how can i make sure i have this directory.  thanks

Comment: do `ls ~/` and see if `bin` is the the list...

Comment: Shouldn't you be linking to ST3, not ST2?

Comment: yes and when i run with command with ST3, am getting this bash: subl: command not found.

Comment: ln: /bin/subl: File exists
DAVID-STROUDs-MacBook-Air:/ david$ subl .
bash: subl: command not found
DAVID-STROUDs-MacBook-Air:/ david$  //this is what I am receiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what should work. First, enter

```
sudo rm /bin/subl
```

Then, enter

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime Text 3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /bin/subl
```

and you *should* be all set. Note that you're linking to the `subl` command in Sublime Text **3**.app.  `/bin` is hopefully in your `PATH` environment variable, if `subl` existed there before, you can enter

```
echo $PATH
```

to find out.

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind, please select the "Accept this answer" check mark to mark the question as resolved. We also both get reputation points! Thanks.

Comment: MAlternative is a shell alias, put to .bashrc or your shell configuration file. The benefit of this is that 1) you don't mess with system folders 2) you can add beneficial command line switches

Answer (score 0):

Might do it this way:

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /bin/subl
```

this way you can use

Comment: ln: /bin/subl: File exists  //is the response i get from the command above.  still not working

Comment: you can try with this:
sudo mv /bin/subl /bin/subl_backup
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /bin/subl

Comment: still not working.  i will keep searching.  thanks for your help

Comment: when i run the command above and change to Sublime Text 3, I get the following//        ln: /bin/subl: File exists
DAVID-STROUDs-MacBook-Air:/ david$ subl .
bash: subl: command not found
DAVID-STROUDs-MacBook-Air:/ david$